# wxwidgets app in Visual Studio gives error "LNK2019 unresolved external symbol"

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Im creating my first program with C++ and wxwidgets. 
When I try to compile the project I get errors.

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

LNK1120 1 unresolved externals
```

I have compiled the wxwidgets my self in Visual Studio.

After compiling I created a new C++ empty project in Visual Studio.

I went to configuration and added includes directories:

**Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional include directories:**

C:\Users\user\source\repos\wxWidgets\include; C:\Users\user\source\repos\wxWidgets\include\msvc

**Configuration properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories:**

C:\Users\user\source\repos\wxWidgets\lib\vc_lib

Then I added 2 classes, cApp and cMain.

**cApp.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "cMain.h"

class cApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    cApp();
    ~cApp();

private: 
    cMain* m_frame1 = nullptr;

public: 
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

**cApp.cpp**

```
#include "cApp.h"

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(cApp);

cApp::cApp() {

}

cApp::~cApp() {

}

bool cApp::OnInit() {
    m_frame1 = new cMain();
    m_frame1->Show();

    return true;
}
```

**cMain.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "wx/wx.h"

class cMain : public wxFrame
{
public:
    cMain();
    ~cMain();
};
```

**cMain.cpp**

```
#include "cMain.h"

cMain::cMain() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "MyProgram") {

}

cMain::~cMain() {

}
```

Comment: No, I dont have a int main(). Where can I define it? Im using wxWidgets.

Comment: I only have the two classes. Im following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOIbK4bJKS8

Comment: I see from the documentation that `wxWidgets` is supposed to implement `int main()` for you. I am not sure why its not doing that.

Comment: Yes, becuase of "wxIMPLEMENT_APP(cApp)".

Comment: You seem to be missing `DECLARE_APP(cApp)` in your header for `cApp`. Not sure if that is needed its in the example code: [https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Hello_World](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Hello_World)

Comment: Hmmm. The error message says it can't find _main but at 22:18 in the video you linked to it says it should be looking for _WinMain. The difference is that _WinMain is used by Windows Desktop Application projects and _main is used by Windows Console Application projects.  Why does it think you want a console app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have <strike>2 problems</strike> (after the edit due to the comment below) the following problem:

1. You're building your application as a console mode application and not a GUI one. While it is possible to use wxWidgets from console applications too, this is probably not what you're trying to do, so ensure that the "Linker|System|SubSystem" option in the properties dialog of your project is set to "Windows".
2. <strike>You don't have `wxIMPLEMENT_APP(cApp);` macro in your code. Again, it is perfectly possible to avoid it, but this is probably not your goal here, so just add this line. This macro is what defines `main` or `WinMain` for your application, depending on the platform.</strike>

Comment: Oops, sorry, I've somehow overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

Your linker wants to find the **main** entry point (main is the default entry point). The wxIMPLEMENT_APP(cApp) macro on the Windows architecture has the **WinMain** entry point.

I have three quick solutions.

1. You can write a macro **#define WinMain main** before macro wxIMPLEMENT_APP(cApp)
2. You can tell the linker the name of the entry point(
   In your case, the name of the entry point is **WinMain**).

project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced and on the right pane of the dialog is a place for the name of the entry point function.

3. Your Visual Studio project has a Console SubSystem installed (this SubSystem looks for the default **main** entry point). You must change the SubSystem value to WINDOWS (this SubSystem looks for the **WinMain** entry point).

Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System and then set the SubSystem property to **Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)**

Comment: `#define WinMain main` did it for me, in my case I was using `wxIMPLEMENT_APP_CONSOLE`